# SharedPreferences doesnt want to store my code

Tags: java, android, authentication, storage, sharedpreferences

I am making a login system on android. I am pretty noob at coding and i need help. I want the user to be able to register a code and then login with it. I have three activities and i will show you two java files. THere is no error in my code. Here is links to the codes:

Register code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/registerCode.png

login code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/loginCode.png

I am having 1234 as a default code, and that is the only code that works. If i try to register a new code i cant us`e it, only 1234. Please help me! :)

Comment: "THere is no error in my code." haven't we all heard that one before? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo mistake. In `registerCode.java` you are using `Code` in your `getSharedPreferences()` whereas in `loginCode.java` you are using `code` in your `getSharedPreferences()`. Please note the difference between `code` and `Code`.

As far as you only able to use `1234` as login code is concerned, since in `loginCode` you are referring the SharedPreferences incorrectly and you have use `1234` as your default value in

`final int code = sharedPreferences.getInt("code",1234);`

**in case of SharedPreferences not detecting a key, it will take the default value**. Since your called SharedPreference doesn't exists so neither does it's key `code`, so it uses the default value that you provided `1234`.